# Do bounty rep deductions count against the Running Ragged hat?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2016

The [Running Ragged description](http://winterbash2016.stackexchange.com/running-ragged) states:

> earn 150 reputation points on three different sites (not including Stack Overflow) within 15 days.

I've not received the hat yet, but I've earned 242 rep on Meta and 160 on Movies & TV:

[image: Meta rep] [image: Movies & TV rep]

On English Language & Usage I've received 372 rep, but I've started a 500-point bounty:

[image: EL&U rep]

For the Running Ragged hat, is the 500 bounty subtracted from the 150-rep total needed?

Even ignoring Dec 21, the day the bounty rep was deducted, I've earned 251 points on EL&U. Is this not sufficient?

Or does a minimum of 15 Winter Bash days need to have elapsed before calculation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the 500 rep that you lost by starting the bounty is included in the total reputation for a 15 day period.  The only thing excluded from the total is the association bonus.

Based on your reputation history, it appears that you are at net-zero since the start of Winter Bash on December 19th:

- Dec 19th: +120
- Dec 20th: -371
- Dec 21st: +128
- Dec 22nd: +98
- Dec 23rd: +15
- Dec 24th: +10

Since we are looking for the total rep change over 15 days, what you've earned so far on EL&U is zero.

Comment: The precision of his rep counts... wow

Comment: Ha, net-zero? Perfect!

Comment: @Hugo unlucky.Something similar happened to me.  I set up 4 bounties on ELL for a total of 450 rep